# Can't load .wav file to the new AKSampler

Tags: ios, swift, audiokit

I'm trying to replace **AKMidiSampler** and **AKPlayer** with the new **AKSampler**, but for some reason the new sampler doesn't play the **AKAudioFiles** that the old ones did.

Here is a small code example that uses all three samplers: **AKMidiSampler**, **AKPlayer**, and the new **AKSampler**.
All loaded with the same **AKAudioFile**.
If ran the way it is, no sound is played.

When uncommenting

```
player.play()
```

or the

```
try auSampler.play(noteNumber: 60, velocity: 127, channel: 0)
```

There will be sound.

My guess is that I'm not using the **AKSampleDescriptor** properly, 
I use it as the example [here](https://github.com/AudioKit/AudioKit/blob/master/docs/AKSampler.md#aksampledescriptor-and-loadakaudiofile).

```
import Foundation
import AudioKit

class Conductor {
    var sampler   = AKSampler()
    var auSampler = AKMIDISampler()
    var player    = AKPlayer()
    var mixer     = AKMixer()

    init() {
        do {
            let akfile = try AKAudioFile(readFileName: "Drums.wav")



            let descriptor = AKSampleDescriptor(noteNumber: 60,
                                                noteFrequency: Float(AKPolyphonicNode.tuningTable.frequency(forNoteNumber: 60)),
                                                minimumNoteNumber: 0,
                                                maximumNoteNumber: 127,
                                                minimumVelocity: 0,
                                                maximumVelocity: 127,
                                                isLooping: true,
                                                loopStartPoint: 0.0,
                                                loopEndPoint: 1.0,
                                                startPoint: 0.0,
                                                endPoint: 0.0)

            sampler.loadAKAudioFile(from: descriptor, file: akfile)
            try auSampler.loadAudioFile(akfile)
            player = akfile.player

            [player, sampler, auSampler] >>> mixer
            AudioKit.output = mixer
            try AudioKit.start()


//            player.play()
//            try auSampler.play(noteNumber: 60, velocity: 127, channel: 0)
            sampler.play(noteNumber: 60, velocity: 127)



        }
        catch {
            print("ehhhh...")
        }

    }


}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution was simple, I just had to add the line:

```
sampler.buildKeyMap()
```

after loading the samples.
Now everything is working as expected.